# Remove old TimeMachine backups from another machine?

Tags: macos, mac, backup

I have an external hard drive with all my old iMac backups on which go back for about 6 months.  Now, I have a MBPr and I want to use the same drive for my MBP backups.  The issue I have is that my drive is 1TB and my old backups take up about 700GB of that drive, despite the actual used space on my iMac only being 450GB.

What I'd like to do is to remove all but the latest backup from my iMac (which should be 450GB) which leaves me with 550GB for my MBP backup.

What's the best way to do this?  Obviously I can't just delete the old backup folders apart from the last as they're all symlinked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may help you:

Open the terminal in your mac:

Show your backups:

```
tmutil listbackups
```

Show your most recent backup:

```
tmutil latestbackup
```

Delete all backups of device or backup specified:

```
tmutil delete /Volumes/drive_name/Backups.backupdb/mac_name/YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss
```

You can see more in your mac terminal

```
man tmutil
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: Unfortunately this only shows backups made from this machine, not from my previous machine

Comment: you can use ls to show backups in directory of machine and to use this command to delet backups of another machine:
Eg:
tmutil delete /Volumes/drive_name/Backups.backupdb/mac_name/YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss